# Output for Solving an expression does not come as expected

Tags: java, string

> Given a string representing a simple arithmetic expression, solve it and return its integer value. The expression consists of two numbers with a + or – operator between the numbers, i.e., it will of the form x+y or x-y where x and y are not negative

**MyApproach**

I created the NewString and stored the first string till the operator does not come.I took the operator in the character position.I created the second string and stored the rest of the strings into the new String.I then converted them into numbers using parseInt.And then I added the numbers.

What I want to do 123+82=205

I am doing 123+43+82=248.I am not able to figure out how to position the character.

> Can anyone guide me what I am doing wrong?

```
public int solve(String str)
{
  String strnew1="";
  String strnew2="";
  int i=0;
  char ch1=str.charAt(i);
  while((ch1>=48)&&(ch1<=57))
  {
      strnew=strnew+ch1;
      i++;
  }
  int p=str.charAt(i);
  i++;

  while((ch1>=48)&&(ch1<=57))
  {
      strnew2=strnew2+ch1;
      i++;
      if(i==str.length())
      {
          break;
      }


  }
  int n1=Integer.parseInt(strnew1);
  int n2=Integer.parseInt(strnew2);
  n1=n1+p+n2;
  return n1;

}
```

Test Case result.

```
  Parameters          Actual Output   ExpectedOutput

  123+82              248             205
```

Comment: Your code doesn't even run on my IntelliJ.  Can you clean it up and then repost?

Comment: ch1 is the first character of the string, whatever the iteration of the first loop is.

Comment: Why don't you use a `split()`?

Comment: I guess the simplest solution is
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422673/evaluating-a-math-expression-given-in-string-form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use the operator like this.

Well, you add

```
  int p=str.charAt(i);
```

if charAt(i) is a '+' symbol, you add additional 43 ('+' == ascii 43) by implicitly casting a char to int.

Better define 2 cases ('+' / '-') and use the operator:

```
if (p == 43) { //or p == '+'
    return n1 + n2;
} else if (p == 45) {  //or p == '-'
    return n1 - n2
}
return -1; //undefined
```

Comment: Buitink You nailedit.I was thinking of this but I thought If it can be cast and then I also though I need to check for each operation and define the if else

Answer (score 1):

Here is a nice way to accomplish your task. Basically, you iterate till you find the '+' r '-' sign and meanwhile append characters to a String. Now maintain a boolean value which tells you to add or subtract and set this value when you reach the sign. Now, iterate past the operator sign and append characters to another string. Finally, parse them into integers, add/subtract them and return the result.

```
 public static int Solve(String input) //Assume input="100+50" for eg.
    {
        int cnt=0;
        boolean op=false; //Default set to subtract
        String raw_a="", raw_b="";
        while(input.charAt(cnt)!='+')
            raw_a+=input.charAt(cnt++); //The first part
        if(input.charAt(cnt)=='+') //setting the operation
            op=true;
        cnt++;
        while(cnt!=input.length())
            raw_b+=input.charAt(cnt++); //the second part
        int a=Integer.parseInt(raw_a), b=Integer.parseInt(raw_b); //parsing them
        int ans =op? a+b: a-b; //If true then add else subtract
        return ans; //Return the ans
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the ASCII value of `+` -> `43`.

What is the difference between `248` and `205`, `43`.

Got the mistake?

You are not actually adding those 2 numbers, you are adding those two numbers with the ASCII value of the operator.

---

What you should be doing is.

```
if(p == '+')//check if it is a addition
{
 sum = n1 + n2;
}
else
 sum = n1 - n2;
```